# Method to automate deployment installations/updates to numerous vm machines at the same time

Tags: windows

We have a vm enviroment with over 30 agents, I'd like to set up a method or use a software(open source preferably) that will allow me to communicate to all the machines at one time by just working on one. An example being, let's say I want to import an certificate on all the agents, I'd like to go into internet explorer open up tools, content etc.- and perform this task only once but have it applied to All agents.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What OS are you managing? The methods are really different for Linux and Windows, and really weird if you have to do both.

Comment: Windows only! :)

Answer (score 2):

The fact that these are VMs doesn't really make any magic happen, you still have to interact with the guest OS in generally the same ways that you would do to the same system on dedicated hardware.

The best way, using free/included tools, to manage a Windows domain (since you mentioned IE) is to use GPOs. You can add certificates via GPO.

So, looks like you didn't understand me. My first point is: the fact that these machines are VMs really doesn't have much to do with the problem that you're trying to solve. My second point is that a Windows domain *already has* tools that are *built in* that can do a lot of management for you, specifically including the example you mentioned (adding a trusted certificate.) You can also use GPOs to install software to machines in a domain, as long as the installers are in MSI format.

Yes, you can also use Puppet or Chef, which even have free/open source editions. But you should *first* look into the tools that are already built into the operating system before adding more tools. You should self-study and become a Windows sysadmin, or hire/contract one. This site is for systems administators, and if you're just getting introduced to Windows, welcome aboard!

Comment: There is no method to set up installations automatically? for example using Puppet or Chef? but a free alternative..?

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: +1 for the "VMs are not magic" point. That seems so simple yet so many people miss it. Even if a VM infrastructure comes with its own guest OS management tools, these are just one more choice you can use as well as or instead of conventional choices.

Comment: And this isn't the first time I've made the point. Really : All "vm" means is that you can hit the consoles of all the machine via IP, same as if you had a good IP KVM or serial console concentrator.

Comment: thanks Mfinni! I guess I am new to the sysadmin side of windows, the reason I mentioned chef was because the majority of tasks are not certificate related, that was an example- the one we have to do this week is install visual studio 2008 updates across all 25 Vm agents. I guess because they are vm this doesn't make anything easier(as you pointed out)  but I'd like to stay away from creating my own custom scripts if possible, I rather use a software that has the majority of these tasks built in.

Comment: As I said - you can use GPOs to install any software that has an MSI installer to domain members.

Comment: +1 for GPO. @Jlouisfoster note that you can configure baselines easily for software updates if you are using VMWare w/ vCenter and update manager. You didn't mention which flavor your VMs are.

Comment: Any tutorials on how to use GPO for MSI installers? I'm using Vmware, with vsphere center to manager the images.

Comment: At this point, I'm really going to direct you to Google, and repeat : " You should self-study and become a Windows sysadmin, or hire/contract one. This site is for systems administators, and if you're just getting introduced to Windows, welcome aboard!"